# Power set as ring

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory

Let $(\mathcal{P}(M), +, \cdot)$ be a ring and $\mathcal{P}(M)$ is the power-set of $M$. Let $+$ and $\cdot$ be defined as...
$$A+B := (A\cup B)\setminus (A\cap B)$$
$$A\cdot B := A\cap B$$

Am I right in the assumption, that $0_{\mathcal{P}(M)} = \emptyset$ (additive identity) and $1_{\mathcal{P}(M)}=M$ (multiplicative identity)?

Also, I was tasked to find all sets so that $\mathcal{P}(M)$ is a field. So additionally, $(\mathcal{P}(M)\setminus \{0_{\mathcal{P}(M)}\},\cdot)$ must be a abelian group, so we must check if it's commutative and has inverse Elements.

Commutation is not a problem, since $\cap$ is commutative for any elements of $\mathcal{P}(M)$. However, for the inverse element, it must hold true
$$A\cdot A^{-1} = A\cap A^{-1} \overset{!}{=} \underbrace{M}_{1_{\mathcal{P}(M)}} \Rightarrow A, A ^{-1} = M$$
So $M$ itself is the only set in $\mathcal{P}(M)$ so that $(\{M\},+, \cdot)$ is a field.

Am I correct?

Comment: I think what the question means is when this ring is a field - you are right that $M$ is the only element to have an inverse here, so that implies it is a field only when $M$ is the only non-empty subset of $M$. When does this happen?

Comment: @AugustLiu I think it's true for every single-element set, right? Since $\mathcal{P}(\{a\})=\{\emptyset,\{a\}\}$. Then $(\mathcal{P}(\{a\})\setminus \{\emptyset\}, \cdot)$ has the properties we want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is correct until the last sentence which is not clear. You didn't answer the question when is it a field. You got that the only invertible element is $M$ itself. So in order for $P(M)$ to be a field you need the empty set and $M$ to be the only elements of this ring, and this happens exactly when $|M|=1$.

Comment: True, thanks a lot for the clarification =)